# Resume upload using python selenium xpath in naukri.com

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

On the profile page, I'm having trouble using XPath to locate the "resume upload" button. Specifically, the XPath I've been using, `//*[@id="attachCV"]`, doesn't seem to work as expected.

I've attempted several different methods, including incorporating explicit delays to ensure the page has loaded fully. The full XPath for the element is as follows:

xpath
`/html/body/div[3]/div/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/input`
However, when I switch to using the "ID" locator, it works just fine.

What could be the potential causes of the XPath not working as expected? Any insights or suggestions to make it work with the XPath approach would be greatly appreciated.